# client-side exception error of adding an Excel add-in ribbon in a web application from VS2010 debug mode on win7

Tags: asp.net, excel, wcf, iis, vsto

I have published a web service (built in VS2010, .NET 4.0) successfully in my desktop with IIS7.5 win 7 from my laptop.

The C# solution is composed of

```
MyApp.Host , MyApp.Excel, MyApp.WCF, MyApp.Web, MyAppSetup
```

**Now, I need to run the C# code in VS2010 in debug mode on client side (on my laptop)**. 
I have installed VS2010 tools for office runtime. When my application is opened, it will add a tab (an add-in) in Excel 2010. I have copied

```
 MyApp.Excel.dll
 MyApp.Excel.dll.config
 MyApp.Excel.dll.manifest
 MyApp.Excel.vsto
 MyApp.Excel.xlsx
 Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.dll
 Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll
 Microsoft.Office.Tools.dll
 Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.dll
 Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v4.0.Utilities.dll
 Microsoft.Office.Tools.v4.0.Framework.dll
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.dll
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v9.0.dll
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.v10.0.dll
```

to the folder in my C# solution (**on client side, on my laptop**)

```
MyApp.Host\bin\debug\
```

because these files were published to my desktop.

But, I still got error

```
  ************* Exception Text **************
  System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
  at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorkbookImpl.CreateRibbonObjects()
  at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorkbookImpl.WorkbookExtensionImpl.Microsoft.Office Tools.Excel.IWorkbookExtension.CreateRibbonObjects()  at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorkbookImpl.GetRibbonObjects()
```

Do I miss some tools or libs here ?

Answer (score 0):

I regret to tell you but such scenario is not supported...

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

Comment: I just want to run it on client side (on my laptop) in debug mode.

I need to debug it on client side.

The link that you mentioned is about server side.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks